How do I display a default image only if there is no movie poster in this Angular 16 movies app?
I have been working on an SPA with Angular 16, TypeScript and The Movie Database (TMDB).
I show movies in a list (collection), with each movie displayed in MovieCardComponent component that looks like this:
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from '../../models/Movie';
import { Genre, GenreResponse } from '../../models/Genre';
import { MovieService } from '../../services/movie-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-card',
  templateUrl: './movie-card.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-card.component.scss']
})

export class MovieCardComponent {

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) {}

  @Input() movie!: Movie;

  public genreResponse!: GenreResponse;
  public genres: Genre[] | undefined = [];
  public movie_genres: Genre[] = [];

  public movieCardImage: string = !this.movie?.backdrop_path
    ? '/assets/images/generic-card-image.png'
    : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.backdrop_path}`;


    public getMovieGenres() {
      this.movieService.getMovieGenres().subscribe((response) => {
        this.genreResponse = response;
        this.genres = this.genreResponse.genres;

        if (this.genres && this.movie.genre_ids.length) {
          this.movie_genres = this.genres.filter((genre: Genre) => this.movie?.genre_ids.includes(genre.id))
        }
      });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.getMovieGenres();
    }
}

The template:
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img [src]="movieCardImage" [alt]="movie.title" class="img-fluid" />
</div>

The goal
Since not all the movies have posters, I want the card to display a default image, unless the movie does have a poster.
For this purpose, I have:
public movieCardImage: string = !this.movie?.backdrop_path
    ? '/assets/images/generic-card-image.png'
    : `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.backdrop_path}`;

The problem
The problem is that all cards display the default image, and I know for sure that most do have a poster.
Questions

What am I doing wrong?
What is the most reliable way to fix this issue?


How about you set the default value of movieCardImage to be an empty string, then assign the value once the component is ready?

@nhy I have posted some code that works. Thanks for he helping hand. :)

The ternary condition needs to be swapped, this will solve your issue, if the image exists, we show it, else we fallback the default image!
TS
getImage(): string {
    return this.movie?.backdrop_path
    ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.backdrop_path}`
    : '/assets/images/generic-card-image.png';
}

public movieCardImage: string = this.getImage();

html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img [src]="movieCardImage" [alt]="movie.title" class="img-fluid" />
</div>


It does not work.

@RazvanZamfir please share sample data for movies

I have posted some code that works (I tested it). Thanks for he helping hand.

I solved by changing the MovieCardComponent class to this:
export class MovieCardComponent {

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService) { }

  @Input() movie!: Movie;

  public genreResponse!: GenreResponse;
  public genres: Genre[] | undefined = [];
  public movie_genres: Genre[] = [];
  public movieCardImage: string = '';

  public getImage() {
    this.movieCardImage = this.movie?.backdrop_path
      ? `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/${this.movie?.backdrop_path}`
      : '/assets/images/generic-card-image.png';
  }

  public getMovieGenres() {
    this.movieService.getMovieGenres().subscribe((response) => {
      this.genreResponse = response;
      this.genres = this.genreResponse.genres;

      if (this.genres && this.movie.genre_ids.length) {
        this.movie_genres = this.genres.filter((genre: Genre) => this.movie?.genre_ids.includes(genre.id))
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMovieGenres();
    this.getImage();
  }
}


You can use the placeholder attribute and add default image if there is no movie poster:
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img 
    [src]="movieCardImage" 
    [alt]="movie.title" 
    [placeholder]="'/assets/images/placeholder.jpg'" 
    class="img-fluid" />
</div>


I have posted some code that works fine :).
